# PHP - Store a function without executing it

Tags: php, database, sqlite, function

I want to store this:

strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day')

in a variable without having it being executed.

I want to insert this line in a SQLite database but the "strftime" is already a PHP function and it throws an error telling that this line is "false".(Which is true because executed in PHP)

But in SQLite, I know that it is a totally right statement.(I did execute it directly within my database and it gave me what I want)

Here is part of my code:

```
$limitDate = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day');

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO opened_order(name, email, date_limit, pack, details) 
        VALUES(:name, :email, :limitDate, :pack, :details)');

$stmt->bindParam(':limitDate', $limitDate);
```

I'm adding some informations to help.
This is correct while executed directly in a SQLite shell:

```
`INSERT INTO opened_order(name, email, date_limit, pack, details)
 VALUES ('Meh!', 'okok@yes.com', strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day'), 'TD', 'Je veux un ordinateur de moins de 18 kilos.');`
```

But having strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day') in PHP throws an error(Warning: strftime() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given) because strftime of PHP is not the same as the SQLite one.

Comment: You want to store the *string* `"strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day')"` in a database?

Comment: Yes that's it! This is what I'm looking for but I need to "clear" the return of that function in the PHP "environment" because it will throw an error.
I need this function to be fired only in the database "context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have your database call PHP functions, unfortunately. But that's not what you seem to want to do.

What you want to do is call SQLite's own `strftime` function, right?

What you're doing wrong is putting it as a bound parameter. It's not something you're executing in PHP and passing the result of to the database - that's what bound parameters are for. Instead, you want to execute that function as part of the query itself - you want the *database* to execute it. In that case, simply make it part of your query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO opened_order(name, email, date_limit, pack, details) 
        VALUES(:name, :email, strftime(\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\',\'now\', \'+3 day\'), :pack, :details)');
```

See, you bind parameters to prevent SQL injection - you don't want data to be misinterpreted as part of the SQL syntax (what if someone's named `DROP DATABASE;`?). But, in this case, your `strftime` call *isn't* data - it's actually part of the SQL syntax of the query. So you need to put it in the query string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mate, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for!
Thanks a lot! it solved my issue and thanks a lot for the explanation I understood where I was lacking some knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Declare it simply as a String.

```
$var = "strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day')";
```

Hope i understand your Question right!?

**Update:**

When you want to Build your Query dynamicly by using various Variables, you can also use the following Example:

```
$var = "strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day')";
$query = "INSERT INTO opened_order (name, email, date_limit, pack, details) VALUES (:name, :email, $var, :pack, :details)";
```

Comment: Hello,I already tried it but when it is stored in my database it is stored as a String so it did not fire the function.
I want the function to be executed only when it is stored in my database

Comment: So you want to execute this Sting in your SQL Statement? Then Post your Code where you do this.

Comment: Ok I posted it and in fact I want it to be executed while in the database. The function will trigger after the insertion

Answer (score -1):

I think eval will do the the trick.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
<?php
$var = "strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','now', '+3 day');";
eval($var);
?>
```

Comment: Hmm apparently it does not, here's why:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in[...] eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Yes just done it, but I get the same error as before(Warning: strftime() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given ) which is because I execute the function while in a "PHP context"
I need this function to be run after the insert statement and only at this time